# (ksoap2) android to wcf HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 413

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I want to send jpg file from android to wcf server.

I use base64. Anyone knows better idea, let me know please.

Anyway when I debug it, there was a error  HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 413

Please help me.

This is my App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProductService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://182.162.136.28:8733/ProductService"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProductService" contract="MyService.IProductService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProductService" />
</client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status: 413 means that the request you are sending is too large for the wcf server to accept.

You probably have to change the setting for on the wcf side.
Something like this:

`<system.serviceModel> 
<bindings> 
<basicHttpBinding> 
<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" > <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/> <security mode="None"> </security> </binding> 
</basicHttpBinding> 
</bindings>`

Comment: Please edit your comment into your answer (after "**EDIT**), where you can format it better.